# How to display the last two index data of an array as a single data together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Using an array of multiple objects, how can I merge/combine the last two objects data into a single table column to display the data together?

```
{
  row: [
    {
      path: 'CHK_OUT_TYPE',
      value: ''
    },
    ...
    {
      path: 'PRI_PHN_AREA_CD',
      value: '703'
    },
    {
      path: 'PRI_PHN_NR',
      value: '1236578'
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
render() {
  const merge_two_items = (a, b) => ({
    name: a.path + ' + ' + b.path,
    value: a.value + ' ' + b.value
  });
  
  const merge_two_items_r = (b, a) => merge_two_items(a, b);

  const merge_last_two_2 = (arr) => {
    let copy = [...arr];
    copy.push(merge_two_items_r(copy.pop(), copy.pop()));
    return copy;
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      {merge_last_two_2(row).map((row, x) => {
        const path = row.path.includes("index") ? row.path.replace("index", i) : row.path;
        if (row.path.includes("CHK_OUT_TYPE.value")) {
          return <Radio key={x} name={x} onClick={() => this.getRadioBtnData(i)} />
        }
        else {
          return (
            <Table.Cell>{
              row.path.includes("SSN.value") ? formatSSN(_.get(state, path, "")) :
              row.path === 'PRI_PHN_AREA_CD + PRI_PHN_NR' ? formatPhoneNumber(_.get(state, path, "")) :
                _.get(state, path, "")
            }</Table.Cell>
          )
        }
      })}
    </tr>
  )
}
```

I am running into the following error with above code and not sure if there's any other better way to achieve this functionality:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

**Desired output that I want is the ability to see the following result:**

703-123-6578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const data =  [
      {
        path: 'CHK_OUT_TYPE',
        value: ''
      },
      ...
     {
       path: 'PRI_PHN_AREA_CD',
       value: '703'
     },
     {
       path: 'PRI_PHN_NR',
       value: '1236578'
     }
    ]

   export default function App() {
    
      const lastTwoData = data.slice(data.length - 2)
    
      const formatedData = () => {
        let values = []
        lastTwoData.map((d, i) => {
          if (i === 1 ) {
            const value = d.value
            const firstThree = value.slice(0, 3)
            const rest = value.slice(3)
    
            return values.push(firstThree, rest)
          }
         values.push(d.value)
        })
    
        return values.join('-')
    
      }
    
    
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{formatedData()}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      }
```

OUTPUT => 703-123-6578

I think this will help you. You can get last two values and do you calculation according to your needs.

Comment: Providing negative indices will also slice from the end of the array, i.e. `data.slice(-2)` to grab up to the last two elements.